# From Lagrangian of Electromagnetic field to the Lorentz force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

The dynamics of a charged particle with velocity $\textbf{v}$ in electromagnetic field is dominated by the Lorentz force

$$\textbf{F} = q(\textbf{E}+{\textbf{v} \times \textbf{B}}), \tag{1}$$

and the corresponding Lagrangian is

$$L = \dfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - q\phi(\textbf{r},t)+q\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{A}. \tag{2}$$

> My question is: How to derive the equation $(1)$ just from $(2)$ ?

Comment: I just find the answer by this link:http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/itp/lectures/01-Fall/PHY505/09c/notes09c.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80280/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77325/50583

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Okay, could you then please edit your question to include what *specifically* you don't understand about the derivation? The other question gave basically the same information as you do and the hints there should be sufficient to work out the correct derivation.

Comment: I am sorry I just don't follow that question carefully. Almost we are asking the same question. You are right and it should be an duplicate question.